Not able to change the Value of Input from Typescript, in ngxDaterangepicker
How to update the Input box through Typescript File, I am adding a button to reflect the changes in input filed in ngxDaterangepicker but not able to do that change from that buttons. Want to Change on Click arrow button startDate and endDate weekly.



previousWeek() {
this.selectedWeekStart = this.selectedWeekStart.subtract(1, 'week').startOf('week');
this.selectedWeekEnd = this.selectedWeekEnd.subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week');
console.log('this.selectedWeekStart', this.selectedWeekStart);
console.log('this.selectedWeekEnd', this.selectedWeekEnd);
// this.selected.startDate = this.selected.startDate.subtract(6, 'days').startOf('day').toDate();
// this.selected.endDate  = this.selected.endDate.subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week');
// this.selected.start = this.selectedWeekStart.utc().toDate();
// this.selected.endDate = this.selectedWeekEnd.utc().toDate()
// this.updateSelectedWeek();

//$('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate('03/01/2014');

this.selected.setStartDate('06/06/2024')
//  this.datePicker.picker.setStartDate('06/06/2024')
// this.datePicker.daterangepicker.start //this.selected.startDate)
  //this.selected.start = 

}
